# Как перебить стили для сгенерированного тега <path>?

Tags: css, html5

Есть фейсбук виджет сгенерированный js скриптом. Как для него перебить стили (изменить значения атрибута `fill`)?

```
<path d="M20,0 C8.7334,0 0,8.2528 0,19.4 C0,25.2307 2.3896,30.2691 
  6.2811,33.7492 C6.6078,34.0414 6.805,34.4513 6.8184,34.8894 
  L6.9273,38.4474 C6.9621,39.5819 8.1343,40.3205 9.1727,39.8621 
  L13.1424,38.1098 C13.4789,37.9612 13.856,37.9335 14.2106,38.0311 
  C16.0348,38.5327 17.9763,38.8 20,38.8 C31.2666,38.8 40,30.5472 
  40,19.4 C40,8.2528 31.2666,0 20,0" id="bubble" 
  fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" style="">
</path>
```

P.S. привязку к `id bubble` пробовал - не работает.

Comment: Артем, убери скриншот и добавь код в тело вопроса.

Comment: Через css значение атрибута не изменить. Попробуйте jquery: $('#bubble').attr('fill', ' здесь то значение, которое хотите задать ')

Comment: Не уверен что сss можно изменить значение этого атрибута. Перебить стили просто, вот например строгая привязка html body path#bubble, а изменить значение навряд c css выйдет

Comment: @humster_spb, с помощью jquery тоже не меняет. Говорят можно как-то "срезать" стили и потом переназначать. Может знаете как такое делается?

Comment: "с помощью jquery тоже не меняет" - а что именно Вы пишете в скрипте? Покажите здесь. И можно ли где-то взглянуть на рабочий пример Вашей проблемы?

Comment: @humster_spb, 
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bubble').attr('fill', '#F50025');
      });`
на сайте maillinker.com синий виджет справа внизу

Answer (score 0):

На Вашем сайте за цвет bubble отвечает следующая конструкция:

```
<linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
    <stop stop-color="#00B2FF" offset="0%"></stop>
    <stop stop-color="#006AFF" offset="0%"></stop>
</linearGradient>
```

В консоли с помощью изменения атрибута stop-color я перекрасил бабл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, Вам необходимо где-то в своих скриптах (после всех подключенных сторонних) прописать:

```
document.getElementById('linearGradient-1').firstChild.setAttribute('stop-color','#F50025');
document.getElementById('linearGradient-1').lastChild.setAttribute('stop-color','#F50025');
```

p.s. А ещё у Вас на 79-й строке синтаксическая ошибка (отладчик ругается):

```
var customfie_id  = "#customfield"+
```

Comment: у меня постоянно валится ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null`. Пробовал ставить таймауты - без результата.

Comment: @ArtemStanislavenko, возможно, где-то не там пишете. Попробуйте прямо на странице перед </body> написать это в <script></script>. Сначала проверьте, удаётся ли получить document.getElementById('linearGradient-1'), затем уже работайте с его дочерними элементами